# Getting XML attributes with PHP

Tags: php, xml

Hey guys, I have looked all around for help but found nothing sadly. I am trying to use PHP to grab the contents of an XML file and pull the data from an attribute. I have checked other tutorials and tried but none worked.

Here is the XML file:

```
<eveapi version="2">
  <currentTime>2011-04-03 03:55:59</currentTime>
  <result>
    <rowset name="notifications" key="notificationID" columns="notificationID,typeID,senderID,sentDate,read">
      <row notificationID="339040500" typeID="75" senderID="1000137" sentDate="2011-04-03 03:53:00" read="0" />
    </rowset>
  </result>
  <cachedUntil>2011-04-03 04:25:59</cachedUntil>
</eveapi>
```

I am trying to pull the data from 'typeID' & 'sentDate'. Also, this XML file may containt multiple  tags.

All help is welcomed, thanks!

Comment: Have you tried simplexml? (http://php.net/simple_xml)

Comment: @Ben It's 2011, I sure hope he's using PHP 5 ;-)

Comment: i have an answer but its a little unorthodox, and dont wanna risk it :/

Comment: @Pascal. Can't assume. Honestly, the things you see in production environments..

Comment: Yeah, I know :-( But, still...

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code :-

```
$xmlstr = '<eveapi version="2">
  <currentTime>2011-04-03 03:55:59</currentTime>
  <result>
    <rowset name="notifications" key="notificationID" columns="notificationID,typeID,senderID,sentDate,read">
      <row notificationID="339040500" typeID="75" senderID="1000137" sentDate="2011-04-03 03:53:00" read="0" />

    </rowset>
  </result>
  <cachedUntil>2011-04-03 04:25:59</cachedUntil>
</eveapi>
';


$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlstr);

print_r ($xml->result->rowset->row['typeID']);
```

Note: If you have multiple row in rowset then in object, the row will be as collection of array. In that case you have to access the typeID like bellow -

```
print_r ($xml->result->rowset->row[0]['typeID']);
```

Comment: In addition, Don't worry about the value as showing **SimpleXMLElement Object**. You can get just the value when you will print/echo the variable.

Answer (score 1):

Putting flame retardant suit on...

```
$string = '<eveapi version="2">
  <currentTime>2011-04-03 03:55:59</currentTime>
  <result>
    <rowset name="notifications" key="notificationID" columns="notificationID,typeID,senderID,sentDate,read">
      <row notificationID="339040500" typeID="75" senderID="1000137" sentDate="2011-04-03 03:53:00" read="0" />
    </rowset>
  </result>
  <cachedUntil>2011-04-03 04:25:59</cachedUntil>
</eveapi>';

preg_match_all('#([\S]+)="(.*?)"#is', $string, $matches);
unset($matches[0]);

$xml = array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]);

print_r($xml);
```

=

```
Array
(
    [version] => 2
    [name] => notifications
    [key] => notificationID
    [columns] => notificationID,typeID,senderID,sentDate,read
    [notificationID] => 339040500
    [typeID] => 75
    [senderID] => 1000137
    [sentDate] => 2011-04-03 03:53:00
    [read] => 0
)
```

Comment: nice, *hold head in shame 'n' quickly deletes his lame answer*

Comment: Knowing the eveapi I think that this answer is irresponsible. @Narg will probably want to do more with XML and a quick n dirty regex isn't the way to go and doesn't teach anyone a thing about how to properly handle XML.